# react js component gets state as null

Tags: reactjs

I have an error while trying to pass a state as a parameter to a component

i already gave console.log and my state is getting response from api

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../../services/api';
import Products from '../Products';
export default class index extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
            this.state={ products: [], filteredProducts:[]}

    }
    componentWillMount(){
         api.get('/products').then( result => this.setState({
            products: result.data.listProducts,
            filteredProducts: result.data.listProducts
        }))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <Products products={this.state.filteredProducts} handleAddToCart={this.handleAddToCart}/>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

My state starts as null and after consuming api it returns correctly, but the state passed to my component is null
my console .log response

> []
>
> (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

erros:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
const productItems = this.props.productItems.map( product => (
```

and my component products:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import util from '../utils';
export default class Products extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        const productItems = this.props.productItems.map( product => (
            <div className="col-md-4">
            <div className = "thumbnail text-center"> 
            <a href={`#${product.id}`}  onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>
                <p>
                    {productItems.name}
                </p>
            </a>
            </div>
                <b>{util.formatCurrency(product.price)}</b>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        )
        )
        return (
            <div className="row">
                {productItems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `this.props.products.map(product => (...))` because that's how you name the props on the parent component

Comment: I already tried it, but my props is null.

Comment: even consuming my api my state is as the initial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to move your side effect into `componentDidMount` and wait for component to be mounted and then does the async call and be refreshed. Meanwhile you need to have an `if` to prevent from loading the child component if the state is empty. so I would change your code to this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../../services/api';
import Products from '../Products';
export default class index extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
            this.state={ products: [], filteredProducts:[]}

    }
    componentDidMount(){
         api.get('/products').then( result => this.setState({
            products: result.data.listProducts,
            filteredProducts: result.data.listProducts
        }))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
             {this.state.ffilteredProducts.length > 0
             ?  <Products products={this.state.filteredProducts} handleAddToCart={this.handleAddToCart}/>
             : null

                }

            </>
        )
    }
}
```

or you can have a `spinner` instead of null

Comment: thansk a lot bro